# XDocument.Save() without header

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-sql

I am editing csproj files with Linq-to-XML and need to save the XML without the `<?XML?>` header.

As `XDocument.Save()` is missing the necessary option, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this with `XmlWriterSettings`, and saving the document to an `XmlWriter`:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("foo",
    new XAttribute("hello","world")));

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
// or to write to a file...
//using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
{
    doc.Save(xw);
}
string s = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: I really should have googled this before. I remember looking to do similar and putting some dreadful string replace hack in to get it working. Nice Find :)

Comment: @MarcGravell, how to show save as popup using same code?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution than the accepted answer is to use [XDocument.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.tostring?view=net-5.0) to get the XML text without the header.

Example:

```
// Load the file
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName);

// Edit the XML...

// Save the edited XML text to file
File.WriteAllText(fileName, xDocument.ToString());
```